# What word can suitably replace "Chronicles" in "Chronicles of Narnia"?

Tags: synonyms, vocabulary

What words can suitably replace "Chronicles" in "Chronicles of Narnia"? Records or Journal doesn't sound good to me, are there any better words?

I wanted to start a blog(for recording my thoughts/excerpts from books/quotes) with the title "Chronicles of my Mind" (which is obviously inspired from "Chronicles of Narnia"), but there's already a blog with that name. That's the primary reason why I'm looking for a good alternative.

Comment: What is your purpose in replacing the word? What's wrong with "chronicles"?

Comment: Annals, archives.

Comment: Have you tried a [thesaurus](https://www.google.ca/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=synonym%20chronicle)?

Comment: I believe *The Anals of Narnia* would be your best bet.

Comment: @JakeRegier Funny, but please bear in mind many of our visitors are not native speakers, and may take you at your word, not realizing that you're joking.

Comment: I too would like to know your purpose.

Comment: @DanBron  actually, I wanted to start a blog(for recording my thoughts/excerpts from books/quotes) with a title **chronicles  of my mind** ( which is obviously inspired from chronicles of narnia)  but there's already a blog with that name. That's the primary reason why I'm looking for a good alternative.

Comment: How about "The hourglass of my mind?"

Answer (score 4):

How about:

> ***Annals*** of Narnia

or, more obviously:

> ***Tales*** of Narnia

Answer (score -4):

**Canticles**, as in *A Canticle for Leibowitz*.

Comment: A canticle is not a chronicle.

Comment: It's a hymn.  (BTW, not my downvote.)

Comment: Learned something new today.

Comment: _Canticle_: an ode to a Welsh sea anemone.